# Rotate Image not working in Firefox

Tags: css, google-chrome, firefox

Here is my css code

```
  .buildrag-toggle {
      -webkit-transform: rotate(180deg);
      -webkit-transition: 300ms ease all;
      -moz-transition: 300ms ease all;
      -o-transition: 300ms ease all;
      transition: 300ms ease all;
    }
```

Can you please explain why this is not working in Firefox only on other browsers?

Comment: You are writing `-webkit-transform`, it only works in Chrome/Safari. Write `transform: rotate(180deg)` without `-webkit-` prefix and it works in all browsers (IE included)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Write the standard rule, `-webkit-` prefix only works in chrome/safari

```
.buildrag-toggle {
  -webkit-transform: rotate(180deg); /* chrome / safari only */
  transform: rotate(180deg); /* standard */
  -webkit-transition: 300ms ease all;
  -moz-transition: 300ms ease all;
  -o-transition: 300ms ease all;
  transition: 300ms ease all;
}
```

Comment: if you also want IE9 support add `ms-transform` see my post

Comment: @CristianPanea please, accept this answer as correct answer (and upvote too)

Answer (score 1):

do not use only `-webkit-transform` also add transform: `transform: rotate(180deg)`

you could also add `ms-transform` for IE9 support

eg.:

```
-ms-transform: rotate(180deg); /* IE 9 */
-webkit-transform: rotate(180deg); /* Chrome, Safari, Opera */
transform: rotate(180deg);
```

see: http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css3_pr_transform.asp